# Chosen Jquery doesn't working

Tags: jquery, html-select, jquery-chosen

I have chosen on my page but I have some problem, the chosen doesn't work. This is my code.

```js
  $(".chosen-category").chosen();
```

```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <select class="chosen-category">
         <option>Test 1</option>
         <option>Test 2</option>
      <option>Test 3</option>
    </select>
```

Does I wrong with my code ?

Comment: what your expected ?? and code are worked

Comment: Check for console errors.

Comment: That's doesn't worked for me. Maybe it can be conflict with other scripts ? @Sumitpatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have called

```
 $(".chosen-category").chosen();
```

before select load into document. use code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".chosen-category").chosen();

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: can you post your full html page?

Comment: it's too long if I post my full page

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reason is only in the display, try add: bootstrap.css

//jsfiddle.net/Rfv6t/83/